# Linkage Error in maven project

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I have came across a Linkage Error occurred in a Maven project. Below are the error details.

```
[FATAL ERROR] org.sonar.maven.SonarMojo#execute() caused a linkage error (java.lang.LinkageError) and may be out-of-date. Check the realms:
[FATAL ERROR] Plugin realm = app0.child-container[org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:3.5.1]
urls[0] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-maven-plugin/3.5.1/sonar-maven-plugin-3.5.1.jar
urls[1] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-tree/1.2/maven-dependency-tree-1.2.jar
urls[2] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
urls[3] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-batch/3.5.1/sonar-batch-3.5.1.jar
urls[4] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-core/3.5.1/sonar-core-3.5.1.jar
urls[5] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-plugin-api/3.5.1/sonar-plugin-api-3.5.1.jar
urls[6] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-check-api/3.5.1/sonar-check-api-3.5.1.jar
urls[7] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-colorizer/3.5.1/sonar-colorizer-3.5.1.jar
urls[8] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/10.0.1/guava-10.0.1.jar
urls[9] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar
urls[10] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-channel/3.5.1/sonar-channel-3.5.1.jar
urls[11] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.0.1/commons-io-2.0.1.jar
urls[12] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.2/slf4j-api-1.6.2.jar
urls[13] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-duplications/3.5.1/sonar-duplications-3.5.1.jar
urls[14] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-graph/3.5.1/sonar-graph-3.5.1.jar
urls[15] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
urls[16] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-squid/3.5.1/sonar-squid-3.5.1.jar
urls[17] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/picocontainer/picocontainer/2.14.1/picocontainer-2.14.1.jar
urls[18] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-annotations/3.4.0.GA/hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA.jar
urls[19] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/ejb3-persistence/1.0.2.GA/ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA.jar
urls[20] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-commons-annotations/3.1.0.GA/hibernate-commons-annotations-3.1.0.GA.jar
urls[21] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar
urls[22] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.3.03/xml-apis-1.3.03.jar
urls[23] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.6/commons-configuration-1.6.jar
urls[24] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
urls[25] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.8/commons-digester-1.8.jar
urls[26] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.8.3/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
urls[27] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.4/commons-codec-1.4.jar
urls[28] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/jfree/jfreechart/1.0.9/jfreechart-1.0.9.jar
urls[29] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/jfree/jcommon/1.0.12/jcommon-1.0.12.jar
urls[30] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.6.2/jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.2.jar
urls[31] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.6.2/log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.2.jar
urls[32] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.3.1/xstream-1.3.1.jar
urls[33] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/xpp3/xpp3/1.1.3.3/xpp3-1.1.3.3.jar
urls[34] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/woodstox-core-lgpl/4.0.4/woodstox-core-lgpl-4.0.4.jar
urls[35] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/stax2-api/3.0.1/stax2-api-3.0.1.jar
urls[36] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/stax/stax-api/1.0.1/stax-api-1.0.1.jar
urls[37] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/staxmate/staxmate/2.0.0/staxmate-2.0.0.jar
urls[38] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/xerces/xercesImpl/2.8.1/xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar
urls[39] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/xalan/xalan/2.7.1/xalan-2.7.1.jar
urls[40] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/xalan/serializer/2.7.1/serializer-2.7.1.jar
urls[41] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/mybatis/mybatis/3.1.1/mybatis-3.1.1.jar
urls[42] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-update-center-common/1.5/sonar-update-center-common-1.5.jar
urls[43] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-home/3.5.1/sonar-home-3.5.1.jar
urls[44] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/3.3.2.GA/hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar
urls[45] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.6/antlr-2.7.6.jar
urls[46] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/3.4.0.GA/hibernate-entitymanager-3.4.0.GA.jar
urls[47] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/javassist/javassist/3.4.GA/javassist-3.4.GA.jar
urls[48] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/geronimo-spec/geronimo-spec-jta/1.0-M1/geronimo-spec-jta-1.0-M1.jar
urls[49] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.3/commons-dbcp-1.3.jar
urls[50] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/commons-pool/commons-pool/1.5.4/commons-pool-1.5.4.jar
urls[51] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-classworlds/2.2.3/plexus-classworlds-2.2.3.jar
urls[52] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1/json-simple-1.1.1.jar
urls[53] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-blueprints-core/2.2.0-java5/sonar-blueprints-core-2.2.0-java5.jar
urls[54] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/0.9.30/logback-classic-0.9.30.jar
urls[55] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/0.9.30/logback-core-0.9.30.jar
urls[56] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-deprecated/3.5.1/sonar-deprecated-3.5.1.jar
urls[57] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-java-api/3.5.1/sonar-java-api-3.5.1.jar
urls[58] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.2/gson-2.2.2.jar
urls[59] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/com/h2database/h2/1.3.167/h2-1.3.167.jar
[FATAL ERROR] Container realm = plexus.core
urls[0] = file:/D:/Maven/apache-maven-2.2.1/lib/maven-2.2.1-uber.jar
[FATAL ERROR] org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo#execute() caused a linkage error (java.lang.LinkageError) and may be out-of-date. Check the realms:
[FATAL ERROR] Plugin realm = app0.child-container[org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:1.0]
urls[0] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/sonar-maven-plugin/1.0/sonar-maven-plugin-1.0.jar
urls[1] = file:/C:/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.4.1/plexus-utils-1.4.1.jar
[FATAL ERROR] Container realm = plexus.core
urls[0] = file:/D:/Maven/apache-maven-2.2.1/lib/maven-2.2.1-uber.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/codehaus/plexus/classworlds/realm/ClassRealm) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject"
```

Please give some suggesstions to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar problem trying to run the maven plugin org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.1 with maven 3.0.5.
Its likely that the issue is the plugin that you are trying to run is not compatible with the version of maven that is running it.

It looks like "org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:3.5.1" is the plugin that is failing.  Try either using a different version of the plugin or a different version of maven.

You can check your version of maven using

```
mvn --version
```

and compare that verses the dependicenies and documentation found at http://mojo.codehaus.org/sonar-maven-plugin/ for your version